# Hi. Trying to move some files, but Nautilus progress bar won't come up. (Trusty 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I have been having some trouble with an external hard drive lately, so I have been trying to move as many files off of it before it finally bites the dust.

So I've been able to track progress pretty well so far, but I just discovered that a made an oops with moving files from a folder and now I have to start all over again. I was able to see the progress bar before, but now, all of a sudden, it won't show up any more.

Can anybody figure out just what went wrong here? I'll keep trying to figure out what's wrong, till then, but any help *is* appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

External drives often get enormous memory cache for filesystem. In this case, if you copy files to/from hard drive, the copy process would immediately report success, then go on with actual copying in background. The telltale sign of this is a long unmounting. You may use these files as normal ones right after copying, even edit them, just don't plug off your external HDD without unmounting, which will make sure all background processes finished.
In Terminal, there is `sync` command, which will not return until backgound processes on all drives are finished.